# Store temporary information in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I've a doubt about the best practices related with Sitecore.
I will need to store a form information when the user presses Save button while he's still filling all the form before submit. Therefore, in case he goes to the website in the next day he will see the already filled information and he can submit.Because the form is long and splitted in four steps.

My doubt is more related with the best practices for Sitecore. Where should I store this information?
Should I create a table inside sitecore_core or other existing database and read from there? (If there's any way to do that with Sitecore libs)
Or should I create my own database, probably with just two tables, to store that information?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create your own database and store the information there. It is no best practice to add tables to the Sitecore databases and storing this information inside one of the existing tables (ie Sitecore items) is also not the way to go.

So just go for the custom database.

If you are using user profiles and (xdb) analytics data and want to store the form data there anyway, that could also be an option (using a custom facet).

Comment: You should store the information in a cookie on the user's machine. Your form establishes an expectation with the user that their information will not be "accepted for processing" until they hit "submit". By tapping and replaying that information you beach that expectation.

Comment: The form must be filled with user information if he's logged in. The problem for storing in cookie could be security because the form has personal information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WFFM for saving any form information. In case if you want to send/save any additional information then you add your custom save action. Like for example we save data from the contact us form and newsletter form to Eloqua or Marketo for other purposes using custom action.